Is there a canonical "minimal" Morse decomposition?
Classical Morse theory gives a handle decomposition of a finite dimensional manifold $M$ for every choice of Morse function $f: M \to \mathbb R$. Is there always a Morse function that induces a "minimal" decomposition? In the sense that the number of handles of each index is minimal among all possible choices of handle decompositions of $M$.
For example, the minimal decomposition on the sphere $S^{n}$ would be given by the height function on the standard embedding as the unit sphere into $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.
I would also be interested to know if such a decomposition is necessarily unique, possibly up to some natural notion of equivalence.

A keyword to search for might be "perfect Morse function". For example, the existence of perfect Morse functions on 3-manifolds would imply the Poincare conjecture (now proved by Perelman).

@MarkGrant Thank you! Do I understand correctly that any perfect Morse function is minimal in my sense, but not vice versa?

I'm pretty sure a perfect Morse function is minimal, as if it had fewer critical points of a given index it wouldn't be able to generate the homology in that dimension. As to the vice versa, it sounds to me to be equivalent to the question of whether a perfect Morse function always exists. I must admit to not knowing if there exist manifolds for which a perfect Morse function is known not to exist.

@MarkGrant It seems the answer here constructs a pretty explicit (family of) examples.

Right. So for the Poincare homology sphere, for example, there will be minimal Morse functions that are not perfect.
